# linq query to get different records from two lists

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

i'm having two lists(list1 & list2) and want to get only the records in list1 that are not in list2.

How can i achieve this using `LINQ` expression in `C#`

Answer (score 2):

If both list contains comparable objects then this will do the job:

```
var newlist = list1.Except(list2);
```

otherwise you may need to use custom `IEqualityComparer` to get desired results:

```
var newlist = list1.Except(list2, new YourCustomComparer());
```

Comment: yup, my both lists are comparable objects. used `var newlist = list1.Except(list2);` but its returning all the elements from list1

Comment: If your lists contains objects (let's call them `class A`) in both and you compare them, then `Except` will remove those objects from result that are referenced in both lists. But if your objects reference are different and you want to check if there is in both objects with `A.id` = 1 then you have to write your own comparer.

Comment: got the solution `list1.Where(t => !list2.Select(r => r.COUNTRY_CD).Contains(t.COUNTRY_CD)).ToList() `

Comment: @RohanS This is even better if you do not want to create your own comparer: `list1.Where(t => !list2.Any(r => r.COUNTRY_CD == t.COUNTRY_CD)).ToList()` much faster.

Comment: this solution above list1.Where(t => !list2.Select(r => r.COUNTRY_CD).Contains(t.COUNTRY_CD)).ToList() works perfect.. Thanks Rohaan